# Android List View

Tags: android, list

I am having a main Layout that is not having a list view and on button i am pop up a window in that pop up window i am having a button namely Add Event if i click Add Event button i vil raise another pop up in that there is a List View,. I wanna to list some string Array values in Pop up layout but if i have declare List in Pop up Layout i am getting error but if i create List ID in Main layout i am getting List View in Main Layout but what i want is that i wanna to display my List inside the Pop up layout... HERE is my Code...
PLACE i am getting Error
=--------------------------------------------------------------

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

---

```
public class Main extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
 {

// String name, id_val, title_val, date_val, desc_val, link_val, linkname_val,name_val;
// String[] PROJECTION = { BaseColumns._ID, Constants.TITLE};
// String[] FROM = { Constants.TITLE};
// int[] TO = { R.id.event_txt};
// 

  private String[] mStrings = {
             "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
             "Bresse Bleu", "Brick", "Brie", "Brie de Meaux", "Brie de Melun", "Brillat-Savarin",
             "Brin", "Brin d' Amour", "Brin d'Amour", "Brinza (Burduf Brinza)",
             "Briquette de Brebis", "Briquette du Forez", "Broccio", "Broccio Demi-Affine",
             "Brousse du Rove", "Bruder Basil", "Brusselae Kaas (Fromage de Bruxelles)", "Bryndza",
             "Buchette d'Anjou", "Buffalo", "Burgos", "Butte", "Butterkase", "Button (Innes)",
             "Buxton Blue", "Cabecou", "Caboc", "Cabrales", "Cachaille", "Caciocavallo", "Caciotta",
             "Caerphilly", "Cairnsmore", "Calenzana", "Cambazola", "Camembert de Normandie",
              "Four Herb Gouda", "Fourme d' Ambert", "Fourme de Haute Loire", "Fourme de Montbrison",
              "Washed Rind Cheese (Australian)", "Waterloo", "Weichkaese", "Wellington",
             "Wensleydale", "White Stilton", "Whitestone Farmhouse", "Wigmore", "Woodside Cabecou",
             "Xanadu", "Xynotyro", "Yarg Cornish", "Yarra Valley Pyramid", "Yorkshire Blue",
             "Zamorano", "Zanetti Grana Padano", "Zanetti Parmigiano Reggiano"};
// ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
  private static final String tag = "Main";
  private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
  private Button currentMonth;
  private ImageView prevMonth;
  private ImageView nextMonth;
  private GridView calendarView;
  private GridCellAdapter adapter;
  private Calendar _calendar;
  private int month, year;
  private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
  private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";
  private PopupWindow pw,pw1;
  TextView txt1;
  static ViewHolder holder;
  String title;
  private void getRequestParameters()
   {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null)
     {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      if (extras != null)
       { 
        if (extras != null)
         {
          Log.d(tag, "+++++----------------->" + extras.getString("params"));
         }
       }
     }
   }


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_calendar_view);

    _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Log.v("Months", ""+month);
    year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.v("YEAR", ""+year);

    selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

    prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    currentMonth = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
    currentMonth.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTemplate, _calendar.getTime()));

    nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
    nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    // Initialised
    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.day_gridcell, month, year);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }



  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
    if (v == prevMonth)
     {
      if (month <= 1)
       {
        month = 11;
        year--;
       } else
       {
        month--;
       }

      adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.day_gridcell, month, year);
      _calendar.set(year, month, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      currentMonth.setText(months[_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + "-" +_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      //currentMonth.setText(_calendar.getTime().toString());

      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
    if (v == nextMonth)
     {
      if (month >= 11)
       {
        month = 0;
        year++;
       } else
       {
        month++;
       }

      adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.day_gridcell, month, year);
      _calendar.set(year, month, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      currentMonth.setText(months[_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + "-" +_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      //currentMonth.setText(_calendar.getTime().toString());
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
   }

  // Inner Class
  public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
   {
    final ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
    private final Context _context;
    private final List<String> list;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };


private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
private final int month, year;
int daysInMonth, prevMonthDays;
private final int currentDayOfMonth;
private Button gridcell;

// Days in Current Month
public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int month, int year)
 {
  super();
  this._context = context;
  this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
  this.month = month;
  this.year = year;

  Log.d(tag, "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: " + year);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  currentDayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

  printMonth(month, year);
 }

public String getItem(int position)
 {
  return list.get(position);
 }

@Override
public int getCount()
 {
  return list.size();
 }

private void printMonth(int mm, int yy)
 {
  // The number of days to leave blank at
  // the start of this month.
  int trailingSpaces = 0;
  int leadSpaces = 0;
  int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
  int prevMonth = 0;
  int prevYear = 0;
  int nextMonth = 0;
  int nextYear = 0;

  GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, mm, currentDayOfMonth);

  // Days in Current Month
  daysInMonth = daysOfMonth[mm];
  int currentMonth = mm;
  if (currentMonth == 11)
   {
    prevMonth = 10;
    daysInPrevMonth = daysOfMonth[prevMonth];
    nextMonth = 0;
    prevYear = yy;
    nextYear = yy + 1;
   } else if (currentMonth == 0)
   {
    prevMonth = 11;
    prevYear = yy - 1;
    nextYear = yy;
    daysInPrevMonth = daysOfMonth[prevMonth];
    nextMonth = 1;
   } else
   {
    prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
    nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
    nextYear = yy;
    prevYear = yy;
    daysInPrevMonth = daysOfMonth[prevMonth];
   }

  // Compute how much to leave before before the first day of the
  // month.
  // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday.
  trailingSpaces = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;

  if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 1)
   {
    ++daysInMonth;
   }

  // Trailing Month days
  for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++)
   {
    list.add(String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + 1) + i) + "-GREY" + "-" + months[prevMonth] + "-" + prevYear);
   }

  // Current Month Days
  for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
   {
    Log.v("Current Days",""+String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" + months[mm] + "-" + yy);
    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" + months[mm] + "-" + yy);
   }

  // Leading Month days
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++)
   {
    Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + months[nextMonth]);
    list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-" + months[nextMonth] + "-" + nextYear);
   }
 }

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
 {
  return position;
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {
  Log.d(tag, "getView ...");
  View row = convertView;
  if (row == null)
   {
    // ROW INFLATION
    Log.d(tag, "Starting XML Row Inflation ... ");
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_gridcell, parent, false);

    Log.d(tag, "Successfully completed XML Row Inflation!");
   }

  // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
  gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.day_gridcell);
  gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

  // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

  Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + currentDayOfMonth);
  String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
  Log.d("setText", "Current Day: " + day_color[0]);
  gridcell.setText(day_color[0]);
  gridcell.setTag(day_color[0] + "-" + day_color[2] + "-" + day_color[3]);
  //gridcell.setText(clipBoard.getText());

  if (day_color[1].equals("GREY"))
   {
    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
   }
  if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE"))
   {
    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   }
  if (position == currentDayOfMonth)
   {
    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
   }

  return row;
 }
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
 {

 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Main.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     // inflate our view from the corresponding XML file
     final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_root));
     final View layout1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pop_event));
  final String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();

  pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 200,75, true);
 TextView txt =(TextView)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.pop_txt);
 txt.setText(date_month_year);
  holder = new ViewHolder();
  holder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pop_txt);
  //holder.text1.setText("HIIIIIII");

  pw.dismiss();
  pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 10, 30);


  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), date_month_year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
  Log.v("Button ID",""+R.id.bttn2);

  pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.bttn2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Main.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // inflate our view from the corresponding XML file


     pw1 = new PopupWindow(layout1, 270,370, true);

     TextView txt1 =(TextView)pw1.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.event_head);
     txt1.setText(date_month_year);
     pw1.dismiss();
     pw1.showAtLocation(layout1, Gravity.CENTER, 7, 20);

     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
           getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   }

  });

  layout1.findViewById(R.id.event_bttn2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pw1.dismiss();
    pw.dismiss();
   }

  });

  final EditText et=(EditText)layout1.findViewById(R.id.event_edit_txt);

  layout1.findViewById(R.id.event_bttn1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.v("GET TEXT",""+et.getText());
    clipBoard.setText(et.getText());
    Log.v("SET TEXT",""+clipBoard.getText());
    //gridcell.getId();
    title=clipBoard.getText()+"";
    Log.v("title",""+title);






   }



  });

 }








}



  static class ViewHolder {
   TextView text1;

  }




 }
```

Comment: You should post your log...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display multiple dialogs. Actually, you can create one dialog at once but you can make multiple dialog effect with `Fragment`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844428/5506252) answer.