# Opening AlertDialog inside Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom `Dialog Fragment` and I need to display an `Alert dialog` inside it.

Is it possible to do without closing the `Dialog fragment`? 
When I do it with the `context` provided for the `Dialog fragment` it just closes the `Dialog fragment` and open the `Alert dialog`.

```
case R.id.deleteButton:
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.discard_changes))
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(Device, DELETE_DOC);
                dismiss();
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
    break;
```

**EDIT**

As requested, the whole Dialog code:

```
public class InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Context context;

    private Button btn_cancel;

    NavBar navBar;

    Button addDeviceButton;

    ImageButton deleteButton;

    boolean isEditMode;

    public static int EDIT_INSTALLATIONDOC = 1;
    public static int DELETE_INSTALLATIONDOC = 2;

    private InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice, int action);
    }

    @NonNull
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormDialog(@NonNull Context context, InstallationDocumentDevice installationDocumentDevice, boolean isEditMode, @NonNull OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        this.installationDocumentDevice = installationDocumentDevice;
        this.isEditMode = isEditMode;

        Log.i("DocumentController", "dialog device: " + installationDocumentDevice.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_new_device_form);

        RecyclerView accessoriesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.addNewDeviceAccessoriesRecycler);
        RecyclerView guidancesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.addNewDeviceGuidancesRecycler);
        RecyclerView testsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.addNewDeviceTestsRecycler);

        navBar = findViewById(R.id.navBar);
        if(isEditMode) navBar.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.editing_device) + " " + installationDocumentDevice.getLocalizedDeviceName());
        else navBar.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.adding_new_device) + " " + installationDocumentDevice.getLocalizedDeviceName());

        addDeviceButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewDevice);
        addDeviceButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        deleteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

        if(isEditMode){
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            addDeviceButton.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.add_new_device_title));
        } else {
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

//        navBar.getBackButton().setOnClickListener(view -> dismiss());


        accessoriesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        guidancesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        testsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        accessoriesRecyclerView.setAdapter(new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormAdapter(installationDocumentDevice, this::onClick, InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormAdapter.ACCESSORIES));
        guidancesRecyclerView.setAdapter(new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormAdapter(installationDocumentDevice, this::onClick, InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormAdapter.GUIDANCES));
        testsRecyclerView.setAdapter(new InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormAdapter(installationDocumentDevice, this::onClick, InstallationDocumentDeviceAddFormAdapter.TESTS));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnAddNewDevice:
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(installationDocumentDevice, EDIT_INSTALLATIONDOC);
                dismiss();
                break;

            case R.id.deleteButton:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.datapick_discard_changes))
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, (dialog, whichButton) -> {
                            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(installationDocumentDevice, DELETE_INSTALLATIONDOC);
                            dismiss();
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
//                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(installationDocumentDevice, DELETE_INSTALLATIONDOC);
//                dismiss();
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }

    private void onClick(int position, int tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            //Case Accessory
            case 1:
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Accessory pos: " + position + ". Is checked: " + installationDocumentDevice.getAccessories().get(position).isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            //Case Guidance
            case 2:
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Guidances pos: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            //Case Tests
            case 3:
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Tests pos: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Can i show multiple Dialogs one over another? Is there something like Dialog Z-Level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282927/android-can-i-show-multiple-dialogs-one-over-another-is-there-something-like-d)

Comment: The described behavior is not normal, and isn't really explainable with what's shown. I would mention that the `dismiss()` call you show in the given snippet is being called on the `DialogFragment` (likely inadvertently), but that won't close the `Fragment` until the `AlertDialog`'s button has been clicked. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MikeM. added the whole code

Comment: You're calling `dismiss();` at the end of `onClick()`. That's what's doing it. Showing a `Dialog`, anywhere, does not pause execution of your code. It will immediately continue, and in this case, is dismissing the `DialogFragment` right away.

Comment: @MikeM. well that was a foolish mistake on my behalf, sorry and thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

/* Yes This is Possible You Can Grow through Below My Code which I Use In Recycler Adapter in Holder View Click Event.*/

```
     holder.calendar_day_gridcell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
               // holder.txt_InTime.setText("Helllo");

                try {
                    // Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                    //Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

                    DoubleClickPerform.preventTwoClick(v1);

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    Calendar calendar;
                    int currentHour;
                    int currentMinute;
                    TextView txt_dialog_InTime,txt_dialog_OutTime,txt_dialog_SaveInTime,/*txt_dialog_Delete_InTime*/txt_dialog_SaveOutTime/*txt_dialog_Delete_OutTime*/;
                    ImageView img_clean_in_time,img_clean_out_time;
                    Button btn_close;

                    View view1 = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.in_out_time_dialog, null);
                    txt_dialog_InTime = view1.findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog_InTime);
                    txt_dialog_OutTime = view1.findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog_OutTime);
                    txt_dialog_SaveInTime = view1.findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog_SaveInTime);
                  //  txt_dialog_Delete_InTime = view1.findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog_Delete_InTime);
                    txt_dialog_SaveOutTime = view1.findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog_SaveOutTime);
                   // txt_dialog_Delete_OutTime = view1.findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog_Delete_OutTime);
                    img_clean_in_time = view1.findViewById(R.id.img_clean_in_time);
                    img_clean_out_time = view1.findViewById(R.id.img_clean_out_time);
                    btn_close = view1.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    txt_dialog_InTime.setText(holder.txt_InTime.getText().toString());

                    if(txt_dialog_InTime.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        txt_dialog_OutTime.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txt_dialog_OutTime.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                    btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    txt_dialog_InTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog=  new TimePickerDialog(context,
                                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {


                                            Time time = new Time(hour, minute, 0);

                                            //little h uses 12 hour format and big H uses 24 hour format
                                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

                                            //format takes in a Date, and Time is a sublcass of Date
                                            String s = simpleDateFormat.format(time);

                                            txt_dialog_InTime.setText(s);
                                        }
                                    }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);
                            timePickerDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setContentView(view1);
                    dialog.show();

                    img_clean_in_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            txt_dialog_InTime.setText("");

                        }
                    });
                    img_clean_out_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            txt_dialog_OutTime.setText("");

                        }
                    });

                    txt_dialog_OutTime.setText(holder.txt_OutTime.getText().toString());
                    txt_dialog_OutTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog=  new TimePickerDialog(context,
                                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {


                                            Time time = new Time(hour, minute, 0);

                                            //little h uses 12 hour format and big H uses 24 hour format
                                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

                                            //format takes in a Date, and Time is a sublcass of Date
                                            String s = simpleDateFormat.format(time);
                                            txt_dialog_OutTime.setText(s);
                                        }
                                    }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);
                            timePickerDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setContentView(view1);
                    dialog.show();


                 /*   txt_dialog_Delete_InTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            holder.txt_InTime.setText("");
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                    txt_dialog_Delete_OutTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                           holder.txt_OutTime.setText("");
                            dialog.dismiss();


                        }
                    });
*/
                    txt_dialog_SaveInTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                           holder.txt_InTime.setText(txt_dialog_InTime.getText().toString());

                            apiforSaveTime(txt_dialog_InTime.getText().toString(),txt_dialog_OutTime.getText().toString(), finalRevereseDate);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    txt_dialog_SaveOutTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            holder.txt_OutTime.setText(txt_dialog_OutTime.getText().toString());

                            if(!txt_dialog_InTime.getText().toString().equals(""))
                            {
                                apiforSaveTime(txt_dialog_InTime.getText().toString(),txt_dialog_OutTime.getText().toString(), finalRevereseDate);
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                        .make(holder.itemView, "In Time Is Required", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                                snackbar.show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
```

Comment: First You Can Create Dialog Object and Use it in Any Click Event Like

Comment: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: Using View Object to create view  :                     View view1 = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.in_out_time_dialog, null);

Comment: So the trick is to create a new Dialog instead of using the Alerdialog itself?

Comment: Or how is it different from just creating another AlertDialog on top of my Dialog?